# MySQL: Skip INSERT / UPDATE statement that triggers error but show them in output

Tags: mysql, transaction, import, errors

I have a million of rows of customers to be imported via SQL dump. Customer data will be inserted into main table `customer` and child table `customer_address`

The dump contains the following SQL statements:

**File**: customer-dump.sql

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO customer (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('John', 'Doe');
INSERT INTO customer_address (customer_id, city, country) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'New York', 'USA');
COMMIT;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO customer (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('Lorem', 'Ipsum');
INSERT INTO customer_address (customer_id, city, country) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Chicago', 'USA');
COMMIT;

# So on for N no of customers
```

I am importing via CLI as:

```
mysql -u [user] -p [database] < customer-dump.sql > /tmp/customer-import-error.log
```

**My Queries:**

- How to continue the script execution even if there is a failure in some rows?
- How to show/log errors for failed rows?
- Any advice on such massive import?

Answer (score 0):

it is 2 different problem

**1st is possible errors**, for this You can use [--force](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_force) option

```
mysql -u user -p --force database <
```

and **2nd is speed**

for speed You can check server configuration and adjust it if necessary:

- memory (innodb)
- size of redo log file, default is too small, You can increase it

because You are already have dump file - no reason discuss about single transaction or group transactions.

Comment: Each transaction is pretty tiny; I would not expect the redo log to need any adjustment.

Comment: but 1M of this small transactions, in any case with single thread (from single file into single table) - agree this is not give reasonable effects

Comment: What about adding `INSERT IGNORE` to continue the execution? Will adding `--force`show the errors in the console output? Actually I didn't get it clearly.

Comment: what about - edit big file? :-) if You familiar with sed/perl yes, it possible - IGNORE must be added for each INSERT in file.